Ordering the starting parameter in Scipy Minimizer
Addressing a multi-variable function, Scipy minimizer will start with the smallest value in the initial guess array, regardless of the sort. Assuming that you are using the Nelder-Mead method, is there any way to force scipy.minimize to start with the variables in another order? I have a weighing mechanism in my Cost Function and I'd like to prioritize my largest value in the guess list to achieve my Minimization Tolerance sooner.
def CostFunction(np.array([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]),OtherArguments):
    return a*1 + b*2 + c*3 + d*4 + e*5 + f*6 + g*7 + h*8 + i*9 + j*10
InitialGuessArray = np.array([100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000])
CostFunctionMinimized = minimize(
    CostFunction, 
    InitialGuessArray, 
    args=OtherArguments, 
    method="Nelder-Mead", 
    options={"disp": True, "maxiter" : MinimizeMaxiter}, 
    tol=MinimizeTol, 
    bounds=None
)


a will be a 10 element array (initial guess).  b,c,... come from Arguments tuple, and are not varied during the search. With these scipy functions, you adapt your function to play by its specifactions.  minimize is the 'boss' here.

What is Arguments here?

Following up with what @hpaulj is saying, you should probably have CostFunction(x) and that returns np.dot(x, np.arange(1, 11)). But I am not sure what Arguments is and if it's important here.

By default, Nelder-Mead minimization starts with an initial simplex with N+1 points. The first point is x0, the second point is x0 with the first dimension changed, the third is x0 with the second dimension changed. There is no reason why you need to do that order. You could order the points of the simplex differently, and put x0 as the first point, x0 with the last dimension changed second, etc. You can change the initial simplex using the initial_simplex solver option. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html

Of course, this doesn't really accomplish anything. The order of the points in the simplex doesn't matter for convergence speed - what matters is the shape of the simplex. (AFAIK.) You could also modify the initial simplex by making it larger in particular dimensions.

Dear @hpaulj and jared. Sorry for the confusion. I edited the question. The first input of the CotFunction of course is a 10-element array, and there might be other arguments as well, which are not important here.

Thanks @NickODell for the explanation. Yes, the simplex works as you just mentioned. The simplex in Nelder-Mead method in the first step chooses the first element of the N-dimension array and finds the next points based on that.
